# Digital goods payment: I keep getting invalid request

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to use the "Digital goods payment" workflow because I need to get a "pay key" that I will use with a PayPal Lightbox, but the method doesn't accept my request.

This is the code I use (I'm just hiding the real API keys):

```
import requests

h = {'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID': '******************',
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD': '****************',
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE': '*************************************',
    'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT': 'NV',
    'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT': 'NV',
    'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID': 'APP-80W284485P519543T'}

d = """{'requestEnvelope.errorLanguage': 'en_US',
    'actionType': 'PAY',
    'receiverList.receiver(0).amount': '1.00',
    'currencyCode': 'USD',
    'feesPayer': 'EACHRECEIVER',
    'memo': 'Simple payment example.',
    'cancelUrl': 'http://your_cancel_url',
    'returnUrl': 'http://your_return_url',
    'ipnNotificationUrl': 'http://your_ipn_notification_url',
    'receiverList.receiver(0).paymentType': 'DIGITALGOODS'}"""

r = requests.post('https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay', headers = h, data = d)
```

When I execute the code I get this error:

```
In [16]: r.text
Out[16]: u'responseEnvelope.timestamp=2013-07-02T02%3A52%3A53.685-07%3A00&responseEnvelope.ack=Failure&responseEnvelope.correlationId=ea6514b6f51a7&responseEnvelope.build=6520082&error(0).errorId=580001&error(0).domain=PLATFORM&error(0).subdomain=Application&error(0).severity=Error&error(0).category=Application&error(0).message=Invalid+request%3A+%7B0%7D'
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please note: I've tried also with curl and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The code examples in the PayPal documentation are wrong and/or incomplete. I had to guess the structure of the JSON post by myself.

The correct header is this:

```
h = {'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID': '***************',
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD': '***********',
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE': '************************8',
    'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT': 'JSON',
    'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT': 'JSON',
    'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID': 'APP-80W284485P519543T'}
```

and the correct Python dictionary (to jsonize before passing it to the POST) is this:

```
d = {'requestEnvelope' : {'errorLanguage' : 'en_US'},
    'actionType': 'PAY',
    'receiverList' : {
        'receiver' : [
                        {'email' : '***************', 
                        'amount' : 1.00,
                        'paymentType': 'DIGITALGOODS'}
                ],
    },
    'currencyCode': 'USD',
    'feesPayer': 'EACHRECEIVER',
    'memo': 'Simple payment example.',
    'cancelUrl': 'http://your_cancel_url',
    'returnUrl': 'http://your_return_url',
    'ipnNotificationUrl': 'http://your_ipn_notification_url'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - your jsonizing of Python dict before passing it to the POST saved me a problem which was took a lot of time to fix! +1ed!